# SOLR 5.1 Join query parser with phrases

Tags: parsing, search, join, solr

I have a set of files in the file system, and in the database i have several information about each of those files and other files that dose not exist in the file system  , the data is indexed from both the DB and the file system, the search requireent is as follows; if the query is found in the DESC field (taken from the DB), then the document must be returned, and if found in the content of the file, then the document from the DB related to this file must be returned ( i can join the related documents based on the path of the file), i have two problems, i could not implement the required in a single queryand i found that the join query parser dose not work with phrase, can you help me:
the query:
    /select?fl=*&wt=json&q={!join from=resourcename_s to=FULL_FILE_PATH}test
return only the DB info about the file where "test" is found, but i have another record in the DB that has "test" as its DESC and must be returned, i tried
    /select?fl=*&wt=json&q={!join from=resourcename_s to=FULL_FILE_PATH}test OR test 
b ut it did not work,  i also found that the join query parser dose not work with phrases?

Comment: Have you considered indexing the metadata from the DB together with the content from the file? That would just give you a single document to search for, which would be more efficient and a cleaner layout.

Comment: I cannot do this, i am using a tool "lucidWorks fusion" and when defining a data source, i need to specify if it is a DB or a file system or a web or... etc. the DB also includs data about files that will be added to the file system, i mean there might be some data about files that dose not exist in the system